# JavaScript Temporary Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a Quiz Application and require JavaScript mechanisms to temporarily store data without utilizing MySQL or an Internet Connection.  The Game is a Standalone application.  What techniques or libraries may be useful for such an application to store game data temporarily in the particular instance of running the JS functionality.

Please provide any references that may be useful.

Much appreciated

Comment: You can use [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Comment: Just answered a similar question today: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26026430/965907

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need your data to stay after you leave the page, consider using [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage).

Otherwise, you're fine with localStorage, like I said in the comment, here is a very related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26026430/965907

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies, but localStorage is a bit more modern and provides several advantages. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage for a list of storage options in modern browsers.

localStorage and sessionStorage are very similar, and I'd suggest you just use localStorage. See [HTML5 Local storage vs. Session storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523140/local-storage-vs-session-storage) for a broader discussion.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use javascript cookies. With them you can keep information with a name for as long as you would like. sessionStorage and localStorage are harder to understand and add to your page, but if you are an expert then you could use those. But as I said, I would recommend using cookies.
Good luck with your work!